# Pandas counting first row as header when it should not

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am importing a table from excel and converting it to a pandas dataframe. For some reason it continues to count the first row of data as the header even though I do not have header command.

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(r"/path/to/File.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet2"))
print(df2)
```

this returns

```
 +-+--+--+
 |1|20|70|
 +-+--+--+
0|4|27|50|
 +-+--+--+
1|2|25|30|
 +-+--+--+
2|7|23|80|
...
```

but I need it to return

```
  0  1  2
 +-+--+--+
0|1|20|70|
 +-+--+--+
1|4|27|50|
 +-+--+--+
2|2|25|30|
 +-+--+--+
3|7|23|80|
```

I tried entering a different sheet instead of `sheet2` and it worked with different data. I tried moving the same data to a different sheet but it still didn't work.

I also checked `df2.columns.dtype` and got `dtype('O')` I need it to be `dtype('int64')`.

Comment: `pd.read_excel(r"/path/to/File.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet2", header=None)`  returns a DataFrame

Comment: If you do not specify "header" argument, it is set to 0,meaning the first row. Add header=None in read_excel .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do directly

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name="Sheet2", header=None)
```

As per documentation:

header int, list of int, default 0
Row (0-indexed) to use for the column labels of the parsed DataFrame. If a list of integers is passed those row positions will be combined into a MultiIndex. Use None if there is no header.